# no contextMenu.customItems with AIR?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, air

Have some code that's been in use for quite some time - always compile with mxmlc.  Just compiled it with amxmlc and it gave me errors over the presence of "customItems" - nothing else at all in the entire 1500+ line AS3/flex program.  I took out the customItems reference and it compiles with amxmlc just fine.

Nothing about that feature 'customItems' is indicated to be anything other than active and current in the documentation.  All amxmlc actually does is add a command line argument for AIR to the standard mxmlc.

Answer (score 2):

Dug a little deeper and found out that in AIR,  they use a completely different class for contextMenu called NativeMenu with different properties (for no explained reason).